# How to add forloop in If-Else condition in c#?[CODEDOM]

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, codedom

How to execute the following code in Codedom:

```
if(statement)
{
    for(int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

I'm familiar with CodeIterationStatement and CodeConditionStatement but don't know how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

What type of statement or condition you want to put to execute inside loop is depend upon requirement. I guess there should be a condition inside if statement lets understand by example

```
int a=5;
if(a>1)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
        private CodeConditionStatement makeIfStatementWithLoop(CodeExpression conditionExpr, CodeExpression iterationLimit)
        {
            CodeConditionStatement ifStatement = new CodeConditionStatement();
            ifStatement.Condition = conditionExpr;
            CodeVariableDeclarationStatement iDeclaration = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(int)), "i");
            CodeVariableReferenceExpression iReference = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(iDeclaration.Name);
            CodeIterationStatement loopStatement = new CodeIterationStatement();
            loopStatement.InitStatement = new CodeAssignStatement(iReference, new CodePrimitiveExpression(0));
            CodeAssignStatement incrementStatement = new CodeAssignStatement();
            incrementStatement.Left = iReference;
            incrementStatement.Right = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(iReference, CodeBinaryOperatorType.Add, new CodePrimitiveExpression(1));
            loopStatement.IncrementStatement = incrementStatement;
            loopStatement.TestExpression = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(iReference, CodeBinaryOperatorType.LessThan, iterationLimit);
            CodeVariableReferenceExpression consoleRef = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("Console");
            CodeExpression[] args = new CodeExpression[] { iReference };
            CodeMethodInvokeExpression consoleWriteLineStmt = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(consoleRef, "WriteLine", args);
            loopStatement.Statements.Add(consoleWriteLineStmt);
            ifStatement.TrueStatements.Add(loopStatement);
            return ifStatement;
        }
```